# What is this ASCII character code ?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, character, ascii

[image]

I want ASCII character code of character code which i red circle. 
I want display this symbol in word using C#.
Thanks !

Comment: Those aren't ASCII characters. You can find the *Unicode* value under "Character code" though.

Comment: (Actually, ignore what I said about the Character code part. Instead, open up charmap.exe and look at the "U+...." in the status bar.)

Comment: Actually those are ASCII codes but it's not an ASCII font. Fonts like Symbol and Dingbats predate the adoption of Unicode and re-use ASCII codes for non-ASCII symbols. This is unfortunate and is one part of the reason so many people are confused about terms like "ASCII" and "Unicode". You can see that the dialog boldly proclaims `SEMICOLON` (003B) though the selected symbol is `Ⓐ` (24B6).

Answer (score 3):

The A is U+24B6, B is U+24B7, C is U+24B8, D is U+24B9.

This is unicode because they are not in the ASCII range (\x00-\x7F).

See http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/24b6/index.htm.

Comment: [nitpick] ASCII is in the range 0-7f, not 0-ff. [/nitpick]

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks for catching that

Answer (score 0):

The symbol character map reuses ASCII character codes to display another thing provided you use the correct font. This can lead to subtle issues like m becoming µ (or the reverse!) If you are working with physical units, and you are not using the proper font to render the data it can lead to misleading and wrong information displayed!

Therefore the hints given by others are the best option for modern software: use Unicode! Look at the matching Unicode code for the symbols you need, you'll be independent of the selected font as long as this one provides support for the range you are using (under Windows there is something called [Font Linking](http://www.siao2.com/2005/10/01/476022.aspx) which shall make it work in almost all cases)

Using the same code to display another symbol according to the selected font is an absolute no-go in today's software. The code has a meaning in Unicode and won't be re-used for something else. The only thing that is difficult is to select the correct code if you have very similar "visuals" for the result. I mean there are very similar characters which are used in a different context. Select the proper range first, fonts also support usually natively given ranges and the others are supported through font linking.

Comment: What you say about the Symbol font is true, but does not relate to the question. The screenshort is from a symbol (character) insertion window, using current basic font (the Font dropdown has “(normal text)”, not “Symbol”).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: I thought so too but it seems to be a poorly designed interface. Note that it clearly states both `SEMICOLON` and `003B` for the selected character Ⓐ!